# How to unit test exception when uploading stream to Amazon S3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, junit

I have a following piece of code which uploads json to s3

```
private final S3Client s3Client;
private final String bucketName;

public S3ClientWrapper(final Config s3Config) {
    final String region = s3Config.getString(REGION_CONFIG_NAME);
    bucketName = s3Config.getString(BUCKET_NAME);
    final S3ClientBuilder s3ClientBuilder = S3Client.builder();
    s3ClientBuilder.region(Region.of(region));
    s3Client = s3ClientBuilder.build();
}


 public boolean sendEvents(List<Obj> events) {

        String key = getKey();
        PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(key)
                .build();
        try {
            s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromContentProvider(() -> {
                PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
                GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = null;
                try {
                    gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
                GZIPOutputStream finalGzipOutputStream = gzipOutputStream;
                events.stream().map(Json::writeValueAsString)
                        .map(json -> json + "\n")
                        .forEach(json -> {
                            try {
                                finalGzipOutputStream.write(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                            }
                        });
                try {
                    return new PipedInputStream(outputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }

            }, "application/octet-stream"));
            return true;
        }catch (S3Exception e) {
            log.error("failed to send raw data events to S3", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I want to unit test cases where it fails to upload to S3 and raises an S3Exception. How can I write a unit test to test such a scenario in my function ?

Comment: If you just want to test the exception handling and not actually cause the exception, simply mock the `s3Client` object for this single test (it seems from the code that the injection should not be hard) and stub the client to throw an exception on call. Is that what you want to do or is it something else?

Comment: yes I want to just test the exception handling but how can I stub the client to throw an exception on all ?

Comment: Could you add the `s3Client` field declaration and initialization to your question? It would be easier to propose a more specific solution when knowing how you're creating/injecting the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Mockito here, but the mechanism would be similar in case of other libraries. We need to create the mocked `s3Client` and inject it into the tested class. Before calling the tested method, we have to declare the expected behaviour of the mock, which in this case would be throwing `S3Exception`.

Since a static `S3Client.builder()`method is used, we need to use the `mockStatic` method to mock the client creation and we'll need `mockito-inline`to do that (I will link the docs references below).

```java
@Test
void s3ExceptionThrown() {
    try (var mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(S3Client.class)) {
        // creation of the two mock objects below can be moved before the try
        var builder = mock(S3ClientBuilder.class);
        var s3Client = mock(S3Client.class);
        // to mock a static method we have to use `when` method from the object created by `mockStatic`
        mocked.when(S3Client::builder).thenReturn(builder);
        // here we mock non-static methods, so standard `Mockito.mock` method can be used
        when(builder.build()).thenReturn(s3Client);
        when(s3Client.putObject(any(), any(), any()).thenThrow(new S3Exception());
        var testedWrapper = new S3ClientWrapper(/* config */);
        
        var result = testedWrapper.sendEvents(null); // param irrelevant for this test
        
        assertFalse(result);
   } 
}
```

*(important note: the code was written in a notepad on a mobile phone, so it may not compile well, but the mechanism is shown and as a concept should be working fine)*

- [mockStatic](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.8.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks)
- [mockito-inline](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.8.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mockito-inline)